# Not getting correct output in django filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have following models.

```
class Stocks(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class Advice(models.Model):
    ticker = models.ForeignKey(Stocks, db_column='ticker', related_name='advices', 
             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    advice_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
class Recommendation(models.Model):
    ticker = models.ForeignKey(Stocks, db_column='ticker', related_name='recommendation', 
             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    target = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to fetch details where Advice.advice_date is latest. but following code gives me all records from advice

```
reco = Recommendation.objects.all().values('ticker__advices__advice_date').filter(ticker__advices__advice_date=datetime.date(2022,1,19))

print(reco)
```

this is what I get:
<QuerySet [{'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 10)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 11)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 12)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 13)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 14)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 17)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 18)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 19)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 10)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 11)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 12)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 13)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 14)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 17)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 18)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 19)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 10)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 11)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 12)}, {'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 13)}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>

this is what I need:
<QuerySet [{'ticker__advices__advice_date': datetime.date(2022, 1, 19)}]

Comment: Do you use a MySQL database?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I use postgresql database

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote values after filter and it worked. **I am not sure why but I am getting the desired result by writing the query like this**:

```
reco = Recommendation.objects.all().filter(ticker__advices__advice_date=datetime.date(2022,1,19)).values('ticker__advices__advice_date')
```